# Definition singular manifold

Tags: general-topology, geometry, definition

I'm looking for the definition of a singular manifold. I haven't found it yet. For instance, in $\mathbb{R}^4$, with $f(x,y,z,t)=xy-zt$, $f^{-1}(0)$ is a singular submanifold. I only found a few examples but not a proper definition.

Does anyone know a definition or a book where I can find one?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.3518 manifold with corners

Comment: I don't think manifold with corners fit my problem. I've checked. In my situation from the definition of a singular submanifold of codimension n, it should be obvious, according to that paper, that the codimension of "the set  of singular parts" is at least n+1.

Comment: I don't think there's one generally accepted definition of singular manifolds. As @user40276 suggested, you might be interested in manifolds with corners; or for other purposes you might consider [analytic varieties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_variety) or [analytic spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analytic_space). Probably a good general definition that subsumes all of these would be "a topological space that contains a dense open subset that is a manifold." Depending on your purpose, you might want to replace "manifold" by "smooth manifold," "complex manifold," etc.

Comment: Thank you Jack Lee, I'll try with that

Comment: Manifolds which, are not smooth, are singular. Now the definition of smooth manifold is well-known.

Answer (score 1):

The most general theory of singular manifolds that I have seen (staying, however, in the framework where one can still talk about differentiable functions, etc) is Matthias Kreck's "stratifolds". See [here](http://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~kreck/stratifolds/DA_22_08.pdf). Stratifolds are more general than analytical varieties (mentioned by Jack Lee) but less general then, say, simplicial complexes. (Even in the context of similicial complexes, one can still talk about differential forms and de Rham complex *to some extent*. This theory was developed by Dennis Sullivan in the early 1970s, with motivation coming from the rational homotopy theory.)

You also may want to take a look in the book "Stratified Morse theory" by Goresky and McPherson.

However, you should also ask yourself, what is it that you are actually interested in, since the theory of singular manifolds is usually aimed at something rather specific. For instance,  the book by Goresky and McPherson is aimed at algebro-geometric applications, while the one by Kreck is aimed at developing algebraic topology using differential tools.

Comment: Do you know if stratifolds with boundary are closed under, say, pushouts of smooth cofibrations?

Comment: @ConnorMalin: No, I do not. You may want to check his book and if it is not there, ask Kreck directly, he is a very nice guy.