# On morse theory and foliations

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, morse-theory, semi-riemannian-geometry, foliations

Consider a manifold $M$ with a morse function $t$. For the regular points, $t^{-1}(c)$ are embeddings, and the homotopy changes as one jumps from one regular point to another. But, my question is: what can one say about the critical points, i.e. $t^{-1}(c)$ where $c$ is the critical point. Looking at examples, I see why this fails to be even a smooth submanifold. This raises the question, as to what we can say about it.

My intuition leads me to ask the following questions: Is it some sort of a stratification? If yes, is it well studied, and where can I find it? Also, if the ambient manifold has a metric structure, is it possible to use it in anyway to induce anything on the substructure?

Comment: Morse theory says that critical sets are either points (for the local max and min) of singular manifolds with isolated quadratic singularities which are described in terms of the Morse index. This will be discussed in any book on Morse theory.  What else would you want to know? As for a metric (Riemannian or Lorentzian), sure, you can restrict it to the critical sets away from the singularities, but the restriction could be degenerate (in the Lorentzian case).

Comment: I see. So the critical sets are singular manifolds? Is there a good reference which talks about singular manifolds?

Comment: See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848448/definition-singular-manifold/850544#850544