# Name for a Certain Generalization of Manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X_{k,n}$ be the space consisting of $k$ copies of $\mathbb{R}^n$ all identified at a single point.  For example, $X_{1,n} = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $X_{2,2}$ is two planes pinched together at a point, i.e. a 'conic section' cone.

You could try to define a "$(k,n)$-cone manifold" as a paracompact $T_2$ space each of whose points has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ *or* some $X_{k,n}$ for fixed $n$ - alternatively, to $X_{l,n}$ for $l \leq k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \lbrace \infty \rbrace$.  Do such spaces have a name, and are there any general theorems about them?  Mostly their algebraic properties I assume are already completely worked out.

In this case, the pinched points will be discrete, which is kind of boring.  So instead recall the definition of the Cantor-Bendixon derivative $\alpha$ of a topological space $X$.  Namely, it is $\alpha(X) = X \setminus \text{(isolated points of } X)$.  The *order type* of a (non-empty) countable set is the minimal number of times you have to take the derivative to get the empty set - if none exists, we say its order type is infinite.  So the order type of a (non-empty) discrete set is $1$, and otherwise it's higher.

Let $\mathcal{D}_m^n$ be the collection of closed, countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with order type $m$ (alt. less than or equal to $m$), where $m$ is finite.  We could define an $(n, k, m)$-cone manifold to be a paracompact Hausdorff space such that every point has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ *or* a quotient of $k$ (alt. less than or equal to $k$) copies of $\mathbb{R}^n$ along any $D \in \mathcal{D}_m^n$.  This seems like the next-nicest generalization.

But this construction doesn't allow "pinches between the pinches."  How would you define a fourth parameter, something like a 'magnitude' or 'depth,' that allows a neighborhood $U$ of a point to be something like "any point in $U$ is from an $(n, k, m)$-cone manifold" without allowing the space to be torn up?

Comment: In the case $n=1$ your spaces are topological graphs. For higher $n$, I do not think there is a name (maybe singular manifolds?). These spaces will be very close to manifolds and most of their properties can be deduced from the ones of manifolds. There are other common notions of "singular manifolds" used in topology, e.g. pseudomanifolds, Sullivan's manifolds with singularities, Kreck's stratifolds; see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848448/definition-singular-manifold/850544#850544).